# Ignore database config in play 2.5.x

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-config, hocon

I am trying to automate some aspect of deploying a play2/sbt app to a restricted containerized environment, and have some limitation in place.

mainly what I am trying to achieve is to set database config for a specific named db connection only when the env variables are set.

Reading though the HOCON format documentation, I expected that the keys will be ignored if I don't set any of the substitution variables, but that wasn't the case, the app still pickups the somedb connection and tries to connect to it.

I suspect that maybe the db.somedb key is created anyway if there is a child key?

What can I do to have the behavior I am looking for.

please note that creating a separate config file and loading it is not an option for me

```
db {
  somedb.driver = ${?DB_DRIVER}
  somedb.url = ${?DB_URL}
  somedb.username = ${?DB_USERNAME}
  somedb.password = ${?DB_PASSWORD}
}
db.somedb.jndiName=${?DB_JNDI}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could set a default value that is overriden by the ENV var like so:

`somedb.driver = "changeme"
 somedb.driver = ${?DB_DRIVER}`

Then you would have to check in your code if its overriden, e.g. with a pattern match.

Comment: Actually I don't want any default value, but I need the key to be totally ignored as if I didn't set it, which is not the case now